# How to chown large group of files based on previous owner id?

Tags: command-line, bash, recursive, chown

I created a new account in OS X and disposed of my old one.

I have a bunch of files that now have owner 501 that need to have ownership changed to me

```
[/usr/local]$ ll 
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  admin   612B Oct 20 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 root  wheel   476B Oct 19 10:43 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 501   admin   116B Oct 19 10:01 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  13 501   admin   442B Oct 19 12:35 Cellar/
drwxr-xr-x   7 501   admin   238B Oct 19 12:17 Library/
-rw-r--r--   1 501   admin   679B Oct 19 10:01 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  42 501   admin   1.4K Oct 20 11:12 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 501   admin    68B Oct 20 11:01 cfg/
drwxr-xr-x   5 501   admin   170B Oct 20 11:08 data/
drwxr-xr-x   7 501   admin   238B Oct 20 11:08 docs/
drwxr-xr-x   4 501   admin   136B Oct 19 12:23 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  11 501   admin   374B Oct 19 12:35 include/
drwxr-xr-x  38 501   admin   1.3K Oct 19 12:35 lib/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    27B Oct 20 10:02 mysql -> mysql-5.5.16-osx10.6-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x  16 root  wheel   544B Sep  9 11:08 mysql-5.5.16-osx10.6-x86_64/
drwxr-xr-x  16 501   admin   544B Oct 20 11:01 share/
drwxr-xr-x   4 501   admin   136B Oct 20 11:01 tests/
drwxr-xr-x   2 501   admin    68B Oct 20 11:01 www/



[/usr/local]$ ll Cellar
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  13 501   admin   442B Oct 19 12:35 ./
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  admin   612B Oct 20 11:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:18 gettext/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:16 git/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:21 glib/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:34 gnutls/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:23 irssi/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:31 libgcrypt/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:30 libgpg-error/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:20 libiconv/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:32 libtasn1/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:35 loudmouth/
drwxr-xr-x   3 501   admin   102B Oct 19 12:17 pkg-config/
[/usr/local]$
```

### GOAL

I want to recursively find all files **and** directories in `/usr/local/` with owner `501` and chown them to `$USER`

### NOTE

Some of the files and directories in this folder are owned by `root`.  These files need to remain untouched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo find /usr/local -uid 501 -exec chown $USER '{}' ';'
```

By the way, [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) also has the `-nouser` option that matches all files with UIDs of deleted users:

```
sudo find /usr/local -nouser -exec chown $USER '{}' ';'
```

would also match files by another deleted user.

Comment: This worked perfectly :)

Comment: @phihag @macek A nice `chown` option is `-c` which is similar to `-v` verbose option but only outputs something if the target files actually changes ownership.